# VS2010 with Razor - Howto set default browser window size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, razor

I develop with 2 wide monitors, and I have roughly 3200 pixels across my desk.  However, I develop applications for a lower common denominator, typically 1024 X 768.  How can I set the default window size to 1024 X 768 when debugging?

I know you can set the default browser and window size using the context menu with an .aspx file, but .cshtml files have no "Browse With" menu option.  I am using the World of VS Browser Switcher, which is great, but I see no way to set the default window size.  I have set one of my monitors to display 1024 X 768, but that's an ugly solution.

How can I set my debug browser window size to 1024 X 768 without giving up my lucious development real estate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE, hit F12 to bring up the developer tools window. Then Tools --> Resize --> 1024 x 768.

There are add-ons for this in FireFox and Chrome as well.

Comment: Not the path I envisioned, but works great.  Following your lead, there is Window Resizer for FireFox 3.1-3.5 (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/window-resizer/), and Window Resizer for Chrome 4.0+ (http://www.chromeextensions.org/appearance-functioning/window-resizer/).  FireSizer (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firesizer/) claims to work with FireFox 1.0-4.0.